# Wordpress "Convert To Blocks" not working: always return HTML block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a peculiar problem with Wordpress (latest version), using the Dox (child) theme. I never had this problem before.

I don't have the Classic plugin installed, as I am very happy using blocks.

When I do a new Block Group, like a normal layout of columns and rows containing some images and paragraphs (all blocks), it all works, and I can save it as a Reusable Block (so I can use it elsewhere).

If I load that Reusable block in another page though, it is always loaded as Classic (!!). If I go and edit the same component in Reusable Blocks, it's still all Blocks and I can edit it still as blocks. So it happens only when loaded in another page.

I'm very confused, I don't understand. It seems when loading a Reusable Block it's loaded as Classic. I can select "Convert to regular blocks" so I don't modify the original Reusable, and it remains Classic.

And if at any point I select "Convert to blocks", I get just an HTML block (!), this is it (*** is just redacted text):

```
<div class="wp-block-group">
<h2>Heading title of the section</h2>
<div class="wp-block-columns">
<div class="wp-block-column">
<div class="wp-block-columns">
<figure><img class="wp-image-3728" src="***.jpg" alt="***"></figure><div class="wp-block-column">
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"></figure>
</div>
<div class="wp-block-column">
<h2 class="has-cnt-ac-color has-text-color"><a href="***" data-type="services" data-id="3496">Link to post</a></h2>
<p>Type here whatever you want</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="wp-block-column">
<div class="wp-block-columns">
<figure><img class="wp-image-3494" src="***.jpg" alt="***"></figure><div class="wp-block-column">
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"></figure>
</div>
<div class="wp-block-column">
<h2 class="has-cnt-ac-color has-text-color"><a href="***" data-type="services" data-id="3487">Link to post</a></h2>
<p>Type here whatever you want</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any idea where I should start investigating this?

I'm on Wordpress 6.1.1 and Dox latest version 1.3.2

Comment: not sure what it was down voted, anyway I amended a 'stray' paragraph, and also changed title to be hopefully better at explaining the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Maybe some screenshots or the markup of your reusable block may help your question. At the moment, its very broad/there could be many reasons. Try including more specifics about your installation including actual version and plugins/theme version.

Comment: thanks @S.Walsh I added some more details and example of the HTML I get instead of the block.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest editing the original reusable block via `[site.tld]/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=wp_block` via 'Edit' and recreate it in the Editor. This way, all the references to your reusable block stay the same where its used in posts/pages, eg. `<!-- wp:block {"ref":1234} /-->`.

What I do notice missing from your markup is the block markup for headings, I would expect to see:

```html
<div class="wp-block-group">
<!-- wp:heading -->
<h2 class="wp-block-heading">Heading title of the section</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->
...
```

This could be why it's converted to HTML as there is some block markup and some missing, so it makes a "best guess" that its plain HTML.

Comment: Editing the block directly in the reusable block always worked. From your observation about missing tags, showing the code of the reusable component I still see the tags there `<!-- wp:group {"layout":{"type":"constrained"}} -->
<div class="wp-block-group"><!-- wp:heading -->
<h2>Heading title of the section</h2>
<!-- /wp:heading -->` I wonder why once used on a normal page, some of these disappear. It seems comments are stripped off? If so I do wonder if some extension/minification is actually cutting them off on the posts edit page?